# Generate series of weeks with their week number and year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with a PostgreSQL database and want to generate a series of weeks (monday as first day of week) with week number, year, start date and end date. I have written the following sql.

```
with weeks as (
    select generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, current_date, '6 day') as week_starting_date
)
select row_number() over (order by concat(weeks.week_starting_date))                                               as id,
       extract(week from weeks.week_starting_date::date)         as week_number,
       extract(year from weeks.week_starting_date::date)         as week_year,
       weeks.week_starting_date::date                            as week_start_date,
       (weeks.week_starting_date::date + interval '6 day')::date as week_end_date
from weeks
```

I noticed that some are duplicated example for week 9, 2020 the result is returning 2 rows as follows:

```
9,2020,2020-02-24,2020-03-01
9,2020,2020-03-01,2020-03-07
```

The correct result is the first record ending 2020-03-01, and its meant to return only one record for each week of the respective year in the range.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: how come your week is 6 days long? `weeks as (
    select generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, current_date, '6 day') as week_starting_date
)`

Comment: Hi @JuliusTuskenis, actually had it as '1 week', but i was getting this for same week above `9,2020,2020-02-26,2020-03-03`, which is wrong. what i want is a monday based week results. so i started tweaking it. does the starting date have to be a monday also?.

Comment: if having 7 days a week does not work in your code - it is not the number of days you should change :) I agree with @Belayer answer.

Comment: Thanks much @JuliusTuskenis for you response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole issue stems from selecting the incorrect start date. You stated that *monday as first day of week*,however you start you calendar on 2020-01-01. That is NOT Monday, it is actually Wednesday. Thus your weeks run from Wednesday through Tuesday. That also gives raise to your week 9 issue as both 2020-02-24 and 2020-03-01 are both in ISO week 9. You correct by changing the start date from 2020-01-01 to 2019-12-30 (or programmatically as `date_trunc('week',date '2020-01-01')`. Also your row_number can be reduces to `row_number() over()`. So:

```
with weeks as (
    select generate_series(date_trunc('week',date '2020-01-01') , current_date, '1 week') as week_starting_date
)
select row_number() over () as id
     ,  extract(week from weeks.week_starting_date)         as week_number    -- ISO Week number 
     ,  extract(year from weeks.week_starting_date)         as week_year      -- ISO Year
     ,  weeks.week_starting_date::date                      as week_start_date
     ,  (weeks.week_starting_date + interval '6 day')::date as week_end_date
  from weeks;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=11cdc7980c3553126fb1af3900a9ff17). You may want to look at rows 1, and 53-54. The values for these columns week_number and week-year **are correct** via ISO 8601 date specification. If these do not work for you then you will likely need to build a user defined calendar table.

Comment: Hi @Belayer, thanks much for your response. You explanation is clear to me. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again @Belayer for pointing out `date_trunc('week',date '2020-01-01')`. this accurately returns the date of the first day (Monday as first day) of the week of the specified date. From the returned date, one can then extract accurately other values such as week number.